# PIVOT and insert every N rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

There are two tables:

First table has two columns with the following data:

```
[col1] [RowIndex]
apple  1
10     2
red    3
pear   4
20     5 
yellow 6
```

Second empty table has 3 columns:

```
[FruitType] [Weight] [Color]
```

I wish to load the first table's [col1] data into the second one but "rotated" and without any aggregation.

Result would would look like this:

```
[FruitType] [Weight] [Color] 
apple        10       red
pear         20       yellow
```

How can i insert data to the second table? I tried PIVOT but cannot wrap my head around.

Comment: How could you know which row match which colunm? is there any order in you first table?

Comment: First you are going to have to normalize that column... don't worry about pivot yet. Define how you associate red to apply and 1 to apple

Comment: You can't, unless there is a way to associate the different records.

Comment: @D-Shih I have edited the question. I have a rowindex (provided by application) in the first table. So the order is always strictly according to that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conditional aggregation in concert with row_number() should do the trick

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([RowIndex] int,[col1] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'apple')
,(2,'1')
,(3,'red')
,(4,'pear')
,(5,'2')
,(6,'yellow')

Select [FruitType] = max(case when col=1 then Col1 end)
      ,[Weight]    = max(case when col=2 then Col1 end)
      ,[Color]     = max(case when col=0 then Col1 end)
 From (
        Select *
              ,Grp = (Row_Number() over (order by [RowIndex]) - 1) / 3
              ,Col =  Row_Number() over (order by [RowIndex]) % 3
         From @YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Grp
```

**Returns**

```
FruitType   Weight  Color
apple       1       red
pear        2       yellow
```

**NOTE:**

If `RowIndex` is **truly sequential**, you can remove the row_number() function and simply use `RowIndex`

Comment: Thanks. Yes the RowIndex is truly sequential.

Comment: @Avithohol Great!  Then you can replace Row_Number() over (order by [RowIndex]) with [RowIndex]

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with some calculation

```
insert into SecondTable ( FruitType,Weight,Color)
SELECT FruitType,Weight,Color
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN  rn % 3 = 1 THEN [col1] END) FruitType,
           MAX(CASE WHEN  rn % 3 = 2 THEN [col1] END) Weight,
           MAX(CASE WHEN  rn % 3 = 0 THEN [col1] END) Color
    FROM (
       SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowIndex) rn
       FROM FirstTable
    ) tt
    GROUP BY (rn - 1) /3
)tt
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f81542ae5609b4b0f54b5c2f8413b5c)